# Does shortestPath( ) function in neo4j use filter criteria provided in where condition?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Does shortestPath( ) function in neo4j use filter criteria provided in where condition? My Cypher query looks as below:

```
match (from:startNode{name:'START'}),(to:endNode{name:'END'}), 
path = shortestPath(((from)-[:NESTED_JOIN|:REFERENCED_JOIN*1..10]-(to))) 
WHERE NONE (n IN nodes(path) WHERE n.type= 'DEACTIVATED') return path
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Neo4j **shortestPath()** function uses criteria provided in **WHERE** clause.

Neo4j documentation says that - if we use predicates the shortest path finding works even faster. The working of shortestPath( ) is explained nicely on their site:
[shortestPath()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/execution-plans/shortestpath-planning/)